# Typescript: Generic function type transforming all function paramters

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, type-inference, typescript-generics

In my project I'm using a generic type called **`Data<X>`** that is transforming the given type **`X`** in a certain way.

Now I want to create a generic function type **`DataFunction<F extends Function>`** that is wrapping all parameters of **`F`** in **`Data<Parameter>`**.

For example I want

```
DataFunction<(a: Type1, b: Type2) => ReturnType>
```

to result in

```
(a: Data<Type1>, b: Data<Type2>) => ReturnType
```

I made it to transform a known number of parameters, this here is wrapping the first Paramter in **`Data<Parameter>`**, leaving the following ones unchanged:

```
type DataFunction<T extends (arg0: any, ...args: any[]) => any>  
    = T extends (arg0: infer A, ...args: infer P) => infer R  
        ? (arg0: Data<A>, ...args: P) => R  
        : any;
```

My question is, how can I also wrap all following paramters in **`Data<Paramter>`**? I want something like this, which is not working:

```
type DataFunction<T extends (arg0: any, ...args: any[]) => any>  
    = T extends (arg0: infer A, ...args: [infer P]) => infer R  
    ? (arg0: Data<A>, ...args: [Data<P>]) => R 
    : any;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
type DataFunction<F> = F extends (...args: infer A) => infer R
  ? (...args: { [K in keyof A]: Data<A[K]> }) => R
  : any;
```

[PG](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=4&ssc=38&pln=4&pc=39#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHAPAFQHzIDeyAvgFBlgCeADiupgGICuICYwA9iFowQLzJGyCAA9IIACYBnZAAoAdErhQA5tIBcyUDGjIAggEpk-Ajr0AlMsmQB+eUoUr1W4gG0A0tpDIA1hCpOGAMAXS0GbH1PEIISY1NkKxstOBAqAG4KSQgEABsVFBhWdi4fGE5OOTgtaTAoUFUAGmQAIy0QZgBbFuhDLRaK3IhUzOy8guQitg5uVpUqmrqG5rbkDu7oZoQtAHJRHYAfHaodvuRa+pBVUZz8qELimZ8WuAAvBfOlq5X2rp6oLa-DYA5CSRaXVRuEJnABunGAkkyFGodGQAAtODDoABGExoDBwFjTUpYFEQIKTCp4TJk9GY6AAJjxESJJW4pNo5OCLyg1MonLpWKgAGZmQTWU8OXQKS9XnygA)